# How can I create an HTML Dropdown list in python code by referring to a list in the code?

Tags: python, html, list, dropdown, cherrypy

I'm trying to create a dropdown list in HTML by taking the values from a list that I produce with my code in python. I create my list in python by taking the strings from a json file and then I would like to show that list in a dropdown list in the HTML page that I start with CherryPy. What my HTML code should be to do so?

This is the part of code that creates the list:

```
def get_lists(self):
    file = open(CONF_FILE, 'r')
    config = json.load(file)
    file.close()
    string = config["URL"] + ":" + config["port"] + "/static" # Genera URL per GET
    data = json.loads(requests.get(string).text)  # GET per ottenere il catalog
    list_gar = [g["name"] for g in data["gardens"]] # Generates list of gardens
    list_pla = [p["name"] for p in data["plants"]]  # Generates list of plants
    list_dev = [d["name"] for d in data["devices"]] # Generates list of devices
```

This is the function that should create the dropdown but I don't know how to write it in order to show the fields of a certain list (let's suppose that here I want to show the list "list_gar"):

```
#function to add the plant
@cherrypy.expose
def addplant(self):
    return """<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <h2>ADD PLANT</h2>
        <form method="get" action="posting_plant" target="_self">
        Select Garden:<br>
          <select name="garden">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="name" value="">
          <br>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a for loop and iterate trough the list in order to make a dropdown item for each element of the list

```
string="""<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h2>ADD PLANT</h2>
    <form method="get" action="posting_plant" target="_self">
    Select Garden:<br>
      <select name="garden">
        """
for i in list_gar:
    string+="""<option value="""+i+"""></option>\n            """
string+="""      </select>
      <br>
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      <br>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>"""
return string
```